# How to integrate zoho 'Mobilisten' to xcode 11

Tags: ios, ios13, xcode11, zoho

i am trying to add 'Mobilisten' through pods to xcode 11, but getting error 'Module compiled with Swift 5.0.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1 compiler'.

Answer (score 0):

You should try updating to Mobilisten 3.1.0

You can find the release notes for the update [here](https://github.com/zoho/SalesIQ-Mobilisten-iOS/releases/tag/v3.1.0).

```rb
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Project Target' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Mobilisten', '3.1.0'
end
```

Add the above version of Mobilisten to your Podfile and run `pod repo update && pod install`

Depending on the version of Swift/Xcode used, you can always find the compatibility matrix for Mobilisten in the installation page [here](https://www.zoho.com/salesiq/help/developer-section/ios-mobile-sdk-installation.html).